# InvalidDrawException on NGM Miracle

Tags: android

I've released an app and it works fine on most phones, but I've got some users with a NGM Miracle with Android 4.0.4 (and 1-2 other phones with 4.0.4) which has problems when drawing.

The exeption they get is this:

```
android.view.GLES20Canvas$InvalidDrawException
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2095)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1787)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4628)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The view contains text views and image views only, no custom views. I've tried to disable the hardware acceleration if that was the problem, but didn't make any difference.

They say that the layout is visible and doesn't crash until they press something, like overflow menu button. They can press back button without the app closes.

I don't have the opportunity to debug with a real phone with the problem, so what I get back is just the exception, which doesn't tell me much, not even where it crashes.

The layout uses a viewpager with support library and three different tabs.

How to solve this matter? Any ideas or solutions? Anyone else seen this error?
Thanks!